# Integrating with PayPal Here using the sideloader api in Titanium Appcelerator (alloy framework)

Tags: paypal, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I would like to use the paypal sideloader api to integrate PayPal Here as described here:
https://github.com/paypal/here-sideloader-api-samples/blob/master/docs/README.md

There are several things I am not sure how it works. Can someone help me understand it/point me in the right direct?

To launch the PayPal Here, you use the following url:

```
paypalhere://takePayment?
accepted=cash,card,paypal
&returnUrl=my_registered_location://takePayment/{result}?Type={Type}&InvoiceId={InvoiceId}&Tip={Tip}&TxId={TxId}
&as=b64
&step=choosePayment
&payerPhone=4155551212
&invoice={ ... json snipped ... }
```

How exactly do "open" this `paypalhere://` schema? I would ideally like to have a button on my view called Pay via PayPal Here and when clicked, execute the above.

Secondly, notice how there is a `returnUrl`? This is a custom url schema for my app. Firstly, how do I register my own url schema (e.g. `myapp://`) and then implement the method `takePayment` to get the payment response data?

Thanks in advance for any help & tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, add a button and call a function like

```
function handlePaypal(){
     if (Ti.Platform.canOpenURL("paypalhere://")) {
         Ti.Platform.openURL("paypalhere://"+ yourstring);
     }
     ...
}
```

However you need to add this schema to your **tiapp.xml** file

```
<ios>
    <plist>
        <dict>
            <.....>
            <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>paypalhere</string>
            </array>
            <....>
        </dict>
    </plist>
</ios>
```

**EDITED**

To handle de URL response, you will need to handle the open event as following:

If your App is designed for Android also, you will need to read the receiving intent data like below, as you are using Alloy, you need to put at app/alloy.js

```
if (OS_ANDROID) {
    Alloy.Globals.receivedURL = Ti.Android.currentActivity.intent.data;
}
```

And finally at the beginning of your **index.js**

```
$.index.addEventListener('open', function (e) {

    if (OS_ANDROID) {
       handleResponse(Alloy.Globals.receivedURL);
    } else if (OS_IOS) {
        //Here we have two cases: App was closed or App still running;
        handleResponse(Ti.App.getArguments().url);
        Ti.App.addEventListener('resume', function () {
            handleResponse(Ti.App.getArguments().url);
        }); 
    }
});
```

After all, you can develop your handleResponse function :)

The receiving parameter it will be the URL from the another app,now you only need to parse.

--

As an alternative, since version 5.2, Titanium supports the Hyperloop [beta] module. You can use it to integrate the native [paypal-ios sdk](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK) to your Titanium App. Maybe it will be more better documented and easy to maintain. You can install using CocoaPods, and access directly via Hyperloop. If you have interest this is a good start point: [How to use Hyperloop in your Titanium App](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/appc-labs-server/downloads/Hyperloop+for+iOS+Programming+Guide.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for this. I now understand how to check if paypalhere url can be opened and then open it. Question: why are you adding *paypalhere* to the *tiapp.xml*? Isn't this where I add *myapp* and register my own url schema?

Comment: Also, once I register my own url schema, e.g **myapp** - how exactly do you implement it? I'm using alloy framework, so is there some code to be written on alloy.js? Or do I need a controller file to handle requests being made to my scheme/url from another app (in this case, callback from paypalhere)

Comment: @Latheesan I edited my answer to try accomplish your question

Comment: Sweet! thanks for that. I will try this out tomorrow and let you know how I got along.